# Select single slicer item from Table VBA

Tags: excel, vba, select, slicers

I am trying to print off reports for selected budget holders (selected from a Budget Holder Table), using the budget holder name to feed into the slicer which then updates various pivot tables. 
The issue is the code selects all the budget holders in the slicer rather than taking the single selected budget holder I am picking up from the table.

```
Sub PrintPDFsSO()

    Dim Lobj As ListObject
    Dim Budholder As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, Number_of_rows As Long
    Dim SourceBk As Workbook
    Dim SlicItem As SlicerItem, SlicDummy As SlicerItem, SlicCache As SlicerCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set SourceBk = ThisWorkbook
    Set Lobj = SourceBk.Sheets("BudHolders").ListObjects("BudHolderList")
    Set SlicCache = SourceBk.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Budget_Holder")

    For x = 1 To Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count   'Budget Holders held in    BudHolderList Table

        Dim BudHolders()
        ReDim BudHolders(1 To Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count) 'as Budholders will only ever hold one budget hodler name, can this be simpified?
        Dim Counter As Long

        Counter = 1

        If Not Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden Then

            Budholder = Lobj.DataBodyRange(x, 3) 'Name of budget holder held in 3rd column of Budget Holder Table

            BudHolders(Counter) = Budholder      'Budholders holds the budget holder name

            Counter = Counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve BudHolders(1 To Counter - 1)

            ' Trying to stop slicers/pivot tables calculating so code setting new filter on budget name doesnt get stuck - but not working
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            For Each ws In SourceBk.Sheets

                For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

                    pt.ManualUpdate = True

                Next pt

            Next ws

            'Code to change budget holder in slicer to next budget holder in selection from Table
            For y = LBound(BudHolders) To UBound(BudHolders)

                With SlicCache

                    .ClearManualFilter           'clears all filters and shows all items in budget holder slicer

                    For Each SlicItem In .SlicerItems

                        If BudHolders(y) <> SlicItem.Value Then 'Tests if the slicer item matches the current a value of budholder

                            SlicItem.Selected = False 'Grinding to a virtual halt on this line as it 'calculates and populates pivot table report'

                        End If

                    Next SlicItem

                End With

            Next y

            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            For Each ws In SourceBk.Sheets

                For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

                    pt.ManualUpdate = False

                Next pt

            Next ws

            'Use budholder name which will populate some graphs etc in workbook with new figures
            SourceBk.Sheets("Graphs - Summary").Range("BudHolder_SG").Value = Budholder

            'Do Printing, saving etc
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround by working with one of the pivot tables rather than with the slicer. Because the tables are all connected (i.e. all have the budget holder as a filter field and are connected via the slicer), when I the budget holder is updated in the PivotField in the Pivot Table, it will update all the either pivot tables with the same PivotField value.

So the code to replace the slicer code in original problem is simply:

```
With sheets ("BudgetHolder").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("BudgetHolder")
.ClearAllFilters
.CurrentPage=Budholder
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you reverse the logic and hide those not wanted? The following code is based on picking up filters from a table and applying to a pivottable.

Note: It will stores all the table filters in an array and then loops this array to apply the filters one at a time to the slicer associated with a pivot.

You would certainly want to make the code more modular and separate out into separate functions / subs the storing of filters, looping of array and any separate actions e.g. generating a report when looping the array 
On mobile so indenting might be a bit off.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintPDFs()

    Dim Lobj As ListObject
    Dim BudHolder As String
    Dim SlicItem As SlicerItem, SlicCache As SlicerCache
    Dim SourceBk As Workbook
    Dim x As Long

    Set SourceBk = ThisWorkbook

    'Picks up Table with budget holder details
    Set Lobj = SourceBk.Sheets("BudHolders").ListObjects("BudHolderList")

    'Picks up slicer which drives pivot tables in workbook
    Set SlicCache = SourceBk.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Budget_Holder")

    Dim BudHolders()
    ReDim BudHolders(1 To Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 1


    For x = 1 To Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

        If Not Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden Then ''Applies to items selected (ie visible) in the Budget Holder Table

            BudHolder = Lobj.DataBodyRange(x, 3)

            BudHolders(counter) = BudHolder

            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next x

    ReDim Preserve BudHolders(1 To counter - 1)


    For x = LBound(BudHolders) To UBound(BudHolders)

       With SlicCache

           .ClearManualFilter

           For Each SlicItem In .SlicerItems

               If BudHolders(x) <> SlicItem.Value Then

                   SlicItem.Selected = False

               End If

           Next SlicItem

       End With

       ‘Rest of code to do print PDF reports etc

    End Sub
```

This is where table is called BudHolderList, pivottable is pivottable 1 and slicer is called Slicer_Budget_Holder.

Table:

[image: Table]

Pivot:

[image: Pivottable]

Comment: Hi QHarr, I don't think this will work with what I am doing because I am taking the budget holder from the filtered list in the Table (Budget Holder List), one at a  time and using that budget holder name to drive various other reports (not using pivot tables) in the workbook, which are then copied out into a new book, saved and printed. So.. I want to use the same single budget holder to filter and create the pivot reports, create all the non pivot reports, and export them, all in the same for/next loop, before moving on to the next budget holder in the source Table. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Hi QHarr - I can't find out how the If UBound(Filter(BudHolders, SlicItem.Value)) = -1 line works. Can you explain?

Comment: BudHolders is an array holding the item names that are selected in the table. The filter =-1 is where the current  Slicer item is not found within that array I.e. is a hidden row.

Comment: But tbh I am a little confused by your description of what else needs to happen. BudHolders is an array holding the selected Budget Holders from the table , you can loop this array to do all the steps you describe per budget holder.

Comment: OK, thanks - I will test it with a simpler version of my main routine. It does strike me as odd that it needs so many lines of code to select a single item in a slicer but I see other solutions to slicer problems also take similar approach - seems like a new function is needed! It might take a day or two before I can find time to test your code out.

Comment: Hi  - I'm afraid it did what I thought it might - it picks up all of the visible budget holders in the Budget Holder Table and then sets the filter in the slicer on all of them. I need the slicer to work on the budget one at a time so all the pivot reports get updated for that budget holder, I print them off and then go on to the next budget holder. The budget holder name is held in the budholder variable - is there not a way of making the slicer work using that variable and running the whole routine through an overarching loop? Thanks for your help so far - your code will still come in handy!

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing. The array holds all the currently selected. You simply need to re-arrange the code so the loop of the array (BudHolders) is on the outside, then inside is the With SliCache... and loop of sliceritems; the  IF test is just against the current array item... If BudHolders(counter) = SlicItem.Value then "do everything".... I think. I will need to have a look tomorrow and will post with an update then.

Comment: Have updated to reflect comments. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I only have Mac at home so can't test latest code but I did rearrange the loops on previous version and set the array so it only picked up the single budget holder at a time and it worked (yay!) but... the loop clearing all filters in the slicer and then testing each slicer item against the budget holder meant the program ground to a halt while the pivot tables updated with each change of filtered line being tested for a match. I tried inserting  manual calc line before the test and a pivottable.ManualUpdate = true line to stop the pivot updating while it went through the loop but to no avail.

Comment: Will need to think but you can also introduce Application.Wait to produce a delay (not ideal way as there should be a solution without introducing a delay).

Comment: The looping of the array and checking should not take much time at all. How you arrange the loops may be the issue but difficult to say.

Comment: I have edited original code in original query above which shows latest position. This works fine for simple pivot/slicer but for large data set and multiple items on slicer and multiple pivot tables it gets stuck on the For Each SlicItem In .SlicerItems loop

Comment: Is it one table, one slicer and lots of pivots?

Comment: The source data is about 80,000 lines, set in a Table, with several columns being calculated fields. There are about 8 pivot tables, all copied from the first one I created, but using different fields and showing different views, and their are about 8 slicers, most connected to all pivot tables, the budget holder being the one that customises the pivots for each of the c.100 budget holders. The file size is 30Mb and saved as .xlb. I could value the source data to reduce size to about 18Mb although don't think that's the issue as source data is not recalculating.

Comment: An interesting link here on slicer performance (https://powerpivotpro.com/2010/07/slicers-and-pivot-update-performance/) so could try some of the suggestions here to improve speed although would prefer a way to temporarily stop pivots from updating until slicer is set with correct budget holder.

Comment: Sounds like it has the makings of a question for the code review site (can’t post link at mo but part of Stack) where questions on efficiency /structuring of working code may be accepted. Have a go implementing suggestions from the article you found and then perhaps draft a question for code review? Myself/Others i’n sure will be happy to review a draft.

Comment: How do I submit a draft question for code review? I'll need to send question and new code.

Comment: For a draft I was more thinking just share a paste bin link comment here and I could have a look. Especially if this thread gets moved to chat. [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) you would post your working code for review mentioning the issues about speed and asking for suggestions on improving the code and the speed of execution. There is guidance on how to ask a question.

Comment: Need help with this extract from code above: `With sliccache

       .ClearManualFilter    

       For Each SlicItem In .SlicerItems
           If UBound(Filter(BudHolders, SlicItem.Value)) = -1 Then 
           SlicItem.Selected = False 
           End If
       Next SlicItem
   End With`    There are 100 items in the slicer and it is grinding to a virtual halt on this line as it 'calculates and populates pivot table report'. The objective is to populate the slicer with a  single budget holder taken from a Table, produce the report pack, and move on to the next.

Comment: i will need to have a look tomorrow. Was the code in my revised answer as slow? Note my code was updated.

Comment: Sorry - missed that. I'll use  your `If BudHolders(x) <> SlicItem.Value` line and see what happens. But as it's still cycling through all items in the slicer I fear it will not improve performance. I have tried stripping out all the slicers, valued the source data but no improvement. Deleting many of the non essential sheets/pivots did help but still too slow.

Comment: Sounds like there is a lot more going on here. You should always remove redundant objects e.g. unused sheets. Have pivottables built off the same cache etc. I will try and find some time to run a few tests tomorrow. Note I updated the whole code.

Comment: Hi, I've updated original code (see above)with your suggestions but still slow. Please note I rejigged your code so that Budholders only holds a single selected budget holder at any one time which is then used in the  <>slicitem.value line. Your code creates a slicer with all the visible items showing in the source Budget holder Table. The real issue remains that the slicer item compare loop checks the current budget holder in bud holders against 175 budget holders in the data set and there seems to be some calculation "running slicer operation" which takes about 0.5 seconds per budgetholder..

Comment: PS My "Need help.." post was my poor attempt at a code review request. As you can probably tell I am a bit of a novice in this world but I persevere because I can see major benefits in cracking this particular chestnut :)

Comment: I think you have these the wrong way round  pt.ManualUpdate = True  and pt.ManualUpdate = False. Also, holding one item at a time in the array is not an efficiency gain.

Comment: I'm still a little uncertain as to why you have changed the code from how my array loop was running, i would have thought it better to insert your improvements into the suggested structure. However, if it runs more swiftly for you then who am i to say. Afraid pastebin didn't preserve my formatting but here is a starter for 10 at a new question possibly for code review https://pastebin.com/a5MY6JGb Remember to be specific (quote directly software message, sizes/numbers of items), say what you have tried and what the result was. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Include info like how many columns there are in the table as well so people have a more accurate idea of the size of the workload.

Comment: Here we go (https://pastebin.com/NWQM5mjh). Thanks for starting this off. Not sure what happens next!

Comment: Looks good but make sure to be consistent with numbers used e.g. If it is 175 budget holders it should be that number throughout the entire text (not 170 as it is currently is  Lines 27,48 and 54 or v.v.). Remove my comment still left in (specific number required) - Line 54. What does  Valued the source data mean? Lines 37 and 56. Maybe  expand a tiny bit on what that means. Then when posting to code review make sure to indent code and use highlighting and spacing as appropriate. If you let me know when posted i can have a look and help with editing.

Comment: Done - comment lines in code got a bit messy. I do need to run your revised code in your way to make I haven't missed something there.

Comment: Ok. Let me know when posted to code review (with VBA tag) and i will have a look.

Comment: Just ran with your suggested structure on main model - same issue with delay in working through the slicer list. Office Christmas lunch beckons. Not sure how productive I'm going to be for rest of day!

Comment: Oh dear. I haven’t had time to try and test with your workload estimates. Sorry. Will have a go in my lunch break. Meanwhile, perhaps post to code review if you feel comfortable with question as is.

Comment: Next dumb question.. do I copy pastebin link into code review?

Comment: No. You ask a question and ensure the example is complete i.e. has the code with it. Have a look at the questions already there with a VBA tag and see which you think are easy to understand and well laid out.

Comment: Note this Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count should probably be held in a variable e.g. LobjCount so you then do  For x = 1 To LobjCount   and  the other reference becomes ReDim BudHolders(1 To LobjCount)

Comment: Thanks. Code request posted - I could only tag with VBA. Couldn't see anything on slicers or pivots

Comment: I have made an edit which is pending review by other users on the site. Good luck.

Comment: No joy yet from code review site but I have found a workaround..
If I update the budget holder in the budget holder field in any one of the Pivot Tables (ensuring multiple selection is switched off), ALL the pivot tables update with the new budget holder (as they are all linked via the slicer?), and the loop takes about 2 seconds which will do me just fine. Gives me enough time to make a coffee while the routine runs for all 170 budget holders.
Still seems odd there does not seem to be a quick way using the slicer route but I’m happy.

Comment: That would work! Nicely done. Post as an answer so others can learn from it.